# CMD remove file extension *.hmtl.deploy to *.html

Tags: cmd, file-extension, removeall

I have a few hundred files in directory that have .deploy some are .html others are .js or .css

What I want to do is remove the .deploy from all files in the directoryX and the child directories.  I have tried using the ren *.html.deploy *.html and the output is .html.html.

I dont use cmd a lot so I am not very familiar with the commands or what terms I should be using with google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
for /r %x in (*.deploy) do ren "%x" *.
```

Comment: The ren *.deploy *. works to rename all the files in current directory but after looking more into ren (rename) it only works in the current directory. I tried to use the same thought process but applied to xcopy and I think I am messing up the syntax.  C:\CurrentFolder\*.deploy C:\NewFolder\*. /S however, this did not remove the extensions as i hoped.

Comment: i have 11 subdirectories that are up to 3 levels deep.  I did a search and it is 631 files.  Enough that I was hoping to find a solution that I could reuse and not have to manualy change each one.

Comment: Try that edit, looks like its working but i had to make the files so its hard to tell if it really works :p

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ren *.deploy *.
```

It works for me. No need of complex for loop.